# PHP find phone number in a string with all possible combinations

Tags: php

I got it working when the number is separated with -. How can I add the parameters for when the numbers are like this:

```
(xxx) xxx xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxxx
xxx-xxx-xxxx
(xxx)xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxx xxxx
```

the php code:

```
//find phone in string
preg_match('/\b\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4}\b/', $phone, $phone_matches); 
$find_phone = $phone_matches[0];
```

EDIT:
I found a way to replace it within the text. So I am still looking for all the formats to apply

```
$hide_phone = preg_replace('/\b\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4}\b/', '[hidden phone]', $phone);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

different approeach:

```
"/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}/"
```

Comment: your `*` should be `?` or update the regex since a _valid_ phone number can be `((800  .-234- -4214`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
preg_match('\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}',$phone, $phone_matches);
```